# Get all the key/values pairs attached with a SWT widget using setData()

Tags: java, swt

Is there any way (apart from Reflection) to get all the key/value pairs set with `setData()`?

```
Text text = new Text(shell, SWT.BORDER);
text.setData("name", "mytext");
text.setData("cat", "theCat");
// get all key/value pairs 
// [name, mytext] , [cat, theCat]
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no support for this.

If you want to store multiple values use a `Map` in a single data key.

```
Map<String, String> dataMap = new HashMap<>();
dataMap.put("key", "value");
...

text.setData("mapKey", dataMap);

// Retrieve map
dataMap = (Map<String, String>)text.getData("mapKey");
```

Comment: Actually my code uses other libraries, so that's not my decision to use Map. Now I guess my only choice is to use Reflection, am I right?

Comment: There is no guarantee that the internal structure of the get/setData code will stay the same or even that it is the same on all platforms. So reflection may be very unreliable.